# Why won't my tkinter countdown timer start over automatically when it reaches zero?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, countdown

I am trying to create a countdown timer that will automatically reset itself when it reaches zero then start counting down again.  I've based this code off another user with very slight modifications, but I am missing something.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import time
import datetime

global endTime
global taktTime

def quit(*args):
    root.destroy()

def show_time():
    # Get the time remaining until the event
    remainder = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
    # remove the microseconds part
    remainder = remainder - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)
    if remainder.days >= 0:
        # Show the time left
        txt.set(remainder)
        # Trigger the countdown after 1000ms
        root.after(1000, show_time)
    else:
        txt.set('complete')
        endTime = datetime.datetime.now() + taktTime

# Use tkinter lib for showing the clock
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("x", quit)
root.after(1000, show_time)

taktTime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

# Set the end date and time for the countdown
endTime = datetime.datetime.now() + taktTime

fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=250, weight='bold')
txt = StringVar()
lbl = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=txt, font=fnt, foreground="white", background="black")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to reset the endTime when the remainder hits zero, but I get an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'endTime' referenced before assignment"

I'm sure this is a simple beginner mistake so thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Put `global endTime` inside the `show_time()` function.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something simple.